# how to implement Auth0 strategy in nestjs based on GraphQL

Tags: graphql, auth0, nestjs

I'm trying to implement passport-auth0 strategy in Nestjs app and I'm using GraphQl for api, in the end I ended up with either

> TypeError: res.setHeader is not a function at Auth0 Strategy.strategy.redirect
>   or
>   OAuth 2.0 authentication requires session support when using state. Did you forget to use express-session middleware?

I have followed the instructions in nestjs documentation still same issue, and I checked github repositories too still no success

```js
    import { use, serializeUser, deserializeUser } from 'passport';
    import { Strategy } from 'passport-auth0';
    import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
    import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';

    @Injectable()
    export class Auth0Strategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
    constructor() {
    super(
      {
        domain: environment.auth0.domain,
        clientID: environment.auth0.clientID,
        clientSecret: environment.auth0.clientSecret,
        callbackURL: environment.auth0.callbackURL,
        state: false // or true
      },
      async (accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) => {
        return done(null, profile);
      }
    );
    use(this);

    serializeUser((user, done) => {
      done(null, user);
    });

    deserializeUser((user, done) => {
      done(null, user);
    });
    }
    }

    import { Injectable, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

    import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

    import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';

    @Injectable()
    export class Auth0Guard extends AuthGuard('auth0') {
    getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have expression imported and configured in your `main.ts`?

Comment: no how can I do that?

Comment: You may want to read up on how to implement passport with sessions if you plan to use sessions, or how to disable sessions if you plan to use something like JWT.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pull off authentication via auth0 using `passport-jwt` and `jwks-rsa`.

```js
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy, ExtractJwt } from 'passport-jwt';
import { passportJwtSecret } from 'jwks-rsa';

import { JwtPayload } from './interfaces/jwt-payload.interface';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      audience: process.env.AUTH0_AUDIENCE,
      issuer: `https://${process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}`,
    });
  }

  validate(payload: JwtPayload): JwtPayload {
    const minimumScope = ['openid', 'profile', 'email'];

    if (
      payload.scope.split(' ').filter(scope => minimumScope.indexOf(scope) > -1)
        .length !== 3
    ) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(
        'JWT does not possess the requires scope (`openid profile email`).',
      );
    }

    return payload;
  }
}
```

A fully working template repository can be found at https://github.com/jajaperson/nestjs-auth0